# Step by Step Form

Tags: php, forms, session, cookies

I want to make an online application which is basically a form which will be filled in steps which might take days before i decide to take it to the next step. Now my question is, how can i get to know that a user has already completed step one and therefore when he/she logs in he is taken to step two and if not to step one.

I am thinking of a function more similar to a session. Can i use a cookie? Any kick starts?

Comment: Do the users register or login before they can start?

Comment: How about a username and link it with a step?

Comment: How about storing that information in DB, i.e; current step of a user. table will contain user_id and current_step and optional updated_on field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the two methods you have to know the status of the user is to use cookies, of course, or database persistence.

Since your user has to be logged in to continue I would suggest the second one. This is, for each step of the form the user takes, save that information in your database. You can persist all the information the user already filled, so for each log in, you will know which fields to show (or which step)

Advantages of this against the cookies is that cookies can be removed by the user, so you will loose this information. Also it will happen if the cookie expires.

With database persistence you can maintain this information all the time you consider correct to wait the user to complete the form.

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether the user has to login to fill in the forms, if the user has to login with a username to fill in form (similar to job applications), then you should store the user's progress in a table so he can start from where he has left off.

If the user is not required to login, you might want to set up session that has no expire time. But I would not recommend this because user can delete the cookie anytime he wishes to.

Answer (score 0):

If the user has an account with your site, you could keep track of their form progression using a column in a database and check to see where they're at when they return.

If they don't have an account with you, I think your best bet would be setting a cookie to tell your form what step the user is on when they come back.

These are just ideas off the top of my head, hope one helps!  Best regards

Answer (score 0):

put new sql database table like, step-1 value-> done step-2 value-> notdone

fill up this value when user press next button in your databse table

---

cookies and session may be flushed by users or cleaner software that why you should use databse table